# same logical address for different arrays created in child and parent process using fork()

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void forkexample() 
{
    int x = 1;

    if (fork() == 0)
       {
            //printf("this is Child ");
            ++x;
            printf("addr of  x=%p\n",&x );
            int* arr1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5); 
            *arr1=5;
            printf("Addr of child arr1=%p arr1[0]=%d\n",&arr1,arr1[0] );
       }
    else
    {
        //printf("this is parent ");
        --x;
        printf("addr of  x=%p\n",&x );
        int* arr2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*5); 
        *arr2=6;
        printf("Addr of parent arr2=%p arr2[0]=%d\n",&arr2,arr2[0] );
    }
}
int main()
{
    forkexample();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

Why &arr1=&arr2?

I know that OS will create NEW address space for a child process with use of Copy-On-Write (COW) approach and the '&' gives the logical address, but here here we are creating dynamically 2 different arrays.

Answer (score 2):

`arr1` and `arr2` aren't arrays, they're pointers. You're printing the addresses of local variables within `forkexample`, just like `x`. If you want to see the address of the memory returned by `malloc`, you need to `printf("%p", arr1)`, not `&arr1`.

Presumably the compiler decided to use the same storage for `arr1` and `arr2` because the scopes of the variables don't overlap. You could test this theory by changing the code to:

```
void forkexample(void) 
{
    int x = 1;
    {
        ++x;
        printf("addr of  x=%p\n", (void *)&x);
        int *arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*5); 
        *arr1 = 5;
        printf("Addr of child arr1=%p arr1[0]=%d\n", (void *)&arr1, arr1[0]);
    }
    {
        --x;
        printf("addr of  x=%p\n", (void *)&x);
        int *arr2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*5); 
        *arr2 = 6;
        printf("Addr of parent arr2=%p arr2[0]=%d\n", (void *)&arr2, arr2[0]);
    }
}
```

... and see whether `arr1` and `arr2` still have the same address.

---

Side note: `printf` `%p` takes a `void *`, not an `int *` or `int **` (which is what you're passing). You need a cast: `printf("%p\n", (void *)&arr1);`

Comment: thanks about %p, but in both parent and child process no matter how big size is allocated using malloc() the sizeof operator gives a constant size=0x4(i.e the size of int here).

Comment: @ShashankRao Then I guess that's the size of a pointer on your platform.

Comment: int *arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*5) but in normal it should give 5*sizeof int i.e 5*4=20B

Comment: @ShashankRao No, it shouldn't. `sizeof EXPR` returns the size of the type of `EXPR`. In your case the expression is `arr1`, which has type `int *`.